# Lua Nvim —— Error loading lua [string ":lua"]:5: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 3) near '['

Tags: lua, neovim

I have a init.vim file and have some embedded lua that was working perfectly fine until just now. It keeps giving me the error below:

> Error loading lua [string ":lua"]:5: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 3) near '['

I have double and triple checked that there are no curly parentheses left opened (or maybe i'm just blind) but it still seems to throw the error. Here is the code:

```
  1 local servers = {'clangd'}
  2 require('neorg').setup {
  3     load = {
  4         ["core.defaults"] = {}
  5         ["core.norg.dirman"] = {
  6             config = {
  7                 workspaces = {
  8                     dev = "~/notes/dev",
  9                     school = "~/notes/school",
 10                 }
 11             }
 12         }
 13
 14     }
 15 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot a comma on line `4`:

```lua
  4         ["core.defaults"] = {}, -- note the added trailing comma
  5         ["core.norg.dirman"] = {
```

to separate it from line `5`.

Lua thinks that rather than forgetting to add a comma you forgot to close the table - it can't tell your intention. In general, when looking for syntax errors, always carefully reread the lines in question - don't limit your search to what the error message says (although you should take the error message as a first hint) since error messages may be inaccurate.